# Node - Difference between npm -v and the real version

Tags: node.js, npm

Using Mac terminal and trying to run a Gatsby site, I am running into a problem.
As far as I found out, it is becase of an old version of Node. Particularly, "Node 6.* doesn't natively support async operations".

Just out for curiosity, the error I get when installing the app is:

```
async sendEvents() {
        ^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/gatsby-telemetry/lib/index.js:3:19)
```

So it looks like a matter of just upgrading.

Here comes the tricky part.

When I run `npm -v`, I get this output: `6.12.0`. Ok, all looks coherent. I get the error because I have version 6.

Then I go `brew upgrade npm` and check out the output: `Error: npm 12.11.1 already installed`.

Any comments?

Comment: `npm` and `node` are two different pieces of software ...

Comment: Do you mean `nvm`?

Comment: check `node -v` instead of `npm -v`

Comment: Did you ever install node *without* using brew?  Have you tried to purge the node install and then reinstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should get the latest stable version of node instead ([Download Node])[1](https://nodejs.org/en/), because the `brew upgrade npm` command only upgrades npm. When you download the .dmg file for Node, you get the latest stable version for Node and NPM.

Then, the npm -v just returns the version of npm you currently have installed on your machine and the real version (will assume `node -v`) is the version of node js running on your machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm new in Node (I guess you already noticed), and I didn't know that brew only talks about npm. Solved! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

NPM is the Node Package Manager. It is not the same as Node itself. To get the current version of Node that's running, `node -v` will tell you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Same thing with Node itself. "node -v" = v6.10.1. But when I go brew upgrade node, I get "node 12.11.1 already installed"

Comment: Do you have NVM installed? If so, you may had 12.11.1 installed but have it set to use 6.10.1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Node and npm are individual modules if you will. You do get npm installed with NodeJS, But they can be installed separately as well. 
So you can end up with two different versions of each.

In addition, you can have node and npm installed locally. Or you could have node and npm installed with homebrew. (in a cellar) In which case you end up with two separate installs. So you may need to check which install is being actively used.

In your case, check what node version you have first.

```
node --version
```

and then you can go from there. If it matches npm version, check what path is linked when you type npm or node.
You may potentially use which command to see which installation is currently being used.

```
which node
```

above command should give you path, copy that path
and run

```
ls -l [copied-path]
```

output from ls -l should give you a path that will tell you which installation is being used.

If above path does not point to brew path, I believe you can run brew link to change that path

```
brew link node
```